# Google Sheets circular dependency error for task management sheet with task dependencies

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have made a sample sheet to show my issue: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YZvdHBT3G9gLM8qhas_LSPWU4prVGoOTbY6pRo1IUA0/edit?usp=sharing.

I am trying to make a task manager. Tasks have:

- Dependencies to other tasks
- Completed status - provided by the user

A task is eligible to be completed only when all of its dependency tasks have been completed.

Here is what I have and what I am trying to do:

`Tasks` sheet:

- `Task Name`
- `User Input - Is Completed` - this is where the user would specify if the task is completed
- `Formula - Are Pre-Requisites Met` - formula to determine if this task's dependencies have been met; more below
- `Formula - Is Really Completed` - formula; a task is only really eligible to be completed when all of its pre-requisites are met

`Dependencies` sheet:

- `Task Name` - Parent task
- `Pre-Requisite - Task Name` - child/dependent task
- `Pre-Requisite - Formula - Is Really Completed` - the value of `Formula - Is Really Completed` from the `Tasks` sheet for this row's `Pre-Requisite - Task Name` (the child/dependent task)

My thought is:

- On the `Dependencies` sheet, for each pre-requisite task, look it up in the `Tasks` sheet and see if it's really done (`Is Really Completed`)
- Then, on the `Tasks` sheet, for each `Task Name`, check the status of each of its pre-requisite task in the `Dependencies` sheet and make sure all are really done.

The issue is this leads to a circular reference error. But I don't think it should. Task B is dependent on task A so to determine if task A is really done we are only checking if task B is done. So there isn't a circular reference.

Not sure how to solve this...

Comment: @player0 thanks for the grammatical fixes. that one always trips me up.

Comment: @marikamitsos and player0 : thanks for the answers but I may close this question after a few days... I changed how I store dependencies and was able to get a formula that gives me what I want. Instead of a lookup table for dependencies, I just added a dependency column to the main table with comma separated values of task names. Then I used `split`, `vlookup`, `arrayformula` and other functions to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

**You can fix that by going to: `File` -> `Speadsheet Settings`**

[image: dep-01]

**Once there,change calculation from `OFF` to `ON`**

[image: dep-02]

Comment: Yah, I saw that. But I'm wondering there must be a way to get this data that doesn't result in a circular reference...

Comment: I think it works fine in a [copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xOnLnXE7KUZIsEmu1SpvpYPUUeC8K5PzT2c7udnYGRI/edit?usp=sharing) that I made. Please have a look.

Comment: I see you set the `Theshold` to 0. I had it the default value of `.05` and it was giving wacky results. This way does seem to work but I'm still wondering if there is a way to do this without getting a circular reference error. Will keep looking. I'll mark this as an answer if I don't find something in a week.Thanks!

Comment: _"wondering if there is a way to do this without getting a circular reference error"_. You would need to re-build your formulas. And still. They are quite interweaved. You could probably use some helper columns.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am thinking but need help with those formulas. Not sure how to do it. The problem is on the `tasks` sheet in filtering for it's dependencies. Because it's output is used to determine if the task is really completed which is fed into the `dependencies` sheet which becomes the circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

**C2 cell would be:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {IFERROR(
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, dependencies!A2:B, 2, 0)), B2:B}, 2, 0), 
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, A2:B, 2, 0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

**and D2 cell would be:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", IF((IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {IFERROR(
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, dependencies!A2:B, 2, 0)), B2:B}, 2, 0), 
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, A2:B, 2, 0)))*(B2:B=TRUE), TRUE), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It isn't giving me the expected output. For example, after adding the formula and checking B2, D2 should get checked since A has no dependencies.